# App Crashing when returning from background

Tags: iphone, ios, crash

My application is crashing when it returns back from the background at certain places:

```
-[UITableViewCellContentView updateToInterfaceOrientation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165470
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView updateToInterfaceOrientation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x165470'
```

The error is always similiar somtimes its with 
    [UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer updateToInterfaceOrientation]

I'm really clueless as to why this is happening, any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Ok, this is how I am creating my table view in the loadView method:

```
int tableCells = [formDS.tableItems count];
    int tableHeight = FORM_TABLE_CELL_HEIGHT * (tableCells);
    UITableView *table = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yCoord, FORM_TABLE_WIDTH, tableHeight) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [table setBackgroundView:nil];
    table.backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(FORM_BODY_COLOR);
    table.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(FORM_BODY_COLOR);
    table.dataSource = self;
    table.delegate = self;
    [localContainerView addSubview:table];
```

Comment: where you are setting selector updateToInterfaceOrientation?

Comment: I am not setting updateToInterfaceOrientation anywhere

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some released object and because of that some other objects now present at the same address in memory receive the call for `updateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Try hitting `COMMAND` + `SHIFT` + `B` (or go to `Product` -> `Analyze` in XCode's top bar menu) to have XCode make a static analyze of your code and get some hints of what might go wrong.

Hope that's going to help!

Comment: I am using ARC, not sure if I need to still worry about it?